# Receiving the "Error in if ((is.null(locs) | is.na(locs)) & is.null(prj)) { : zero length argument" error when trying to get the elevation data

Tags: r, elevatr

I am recently trying to make a terrain map of Switzerland and to that end, I need to get the elevation data for that particular country using the `elevatr` package in R. However when I run the following code chunk, which is something similar to what I have seen online for similar maps,

```
library(elevatr)
library(rgeoboundaries)
library(rgdal)

swiss_bound <- rgeoboundaries::geoboundaries("Switzerland")
elevation_data <- get_elev_raster(locations = swiss_bound, z = 10)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in if ((is.null(locs) | is.na(locs)) & is.null(prj)) { :  zero length argument
```

which does not make sense and I could not find any solution on the web to that problem, either why it does occur and what the solution is. So, I highly appreciate your assistance and thank you for your attention beforehand.

Comment: It has to do something `rgeoboundaries`. Try using `sf` package

Comment: Could you elaborate on that because I am still getting the same error although I have installed the sf library if that is what you meant.

Comment: The get_elev_raster() function expects a data frame or spatial object but if you check the `typeof(swiss_bound)` its list type. Maybe that's an issue. So  try to convert your `swiss_bound` to   sf object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot re-create your exact error, but what I do see with `rgeoboundaries` is that it returns an `sf` object, but does not include the CRS which isn't great...  It looks like it is in EPSG:4326.  Making that assumption, the following code should work for you.  But be careful with this as not having the CRS specified from `rgeoboundaries` leaves a lot of room for problems.

```
library(elevatr)
library(rgeoboundaries)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

swiss_bound <- rgeoboundaries::geoboundaries("Switzerland")
st_crs(swiss_bound) <- 4326
elevation_data <- get_elev_raster(locations = swiss_bound, z = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and warning about the CRS, I guess the problem was the lack of CRS as you mentioned. But with your code chunk, now it worked out